# Why is SSL slowing down my Web Service response?

Tags: http, ssl, coldfusion, https, iis-6

I have a full-scale Website running with ColdFusion 8 on IIS 6. The website performs up to expected standards - a simple HTML page loads in a matter of milliseconds.

I am adding a couple Web Services to this website. When I call the Web Services over HTTPS they are extremely slow (4-5 seconds) compared to HTTP (milliseconds).

To confirm that this is not the actual functionality of the Web Services, I created a test Web Service CFC method that simply returns a one-character string. When running it over HTTP, it returns in 16ms. When running it over HTTPS, it takes any where from 4-5 seconds to respond.

Why are these few Web Services so much slower than the rest of the website which runs on HTTPs with no performance issues?

Comment: The only time it got that much slower for me is when I have `refreshWSDL=true`.

Comment: how are you consuming those webservices? You could try out SoapUI and make sure that that shows the same problems to prove it's in server and not in the client you're using

Comment: @barnyr When I call the Web Services directly in a browser, or when I call them from a different website via CFHTTP. It seems to only be happening in IE9.

Comment: If it's only happening in IE9, I'd suspect it's trying to lookup something and failing. You could try installign Fiddler or Wireshark and monitoring network traffic to see if it's attempting to lookup anything strange. the other way to do that without installing anything is to do ipconfig /flushdns, then make your request, then immediately do ipconfig /displaydns and see what your computer has attempted to resolve during your request. Wireshark is the most reliable of these methods, but the hardest to install and use imho